# Python program that produces sum of negative and positive numbers?

Tags: python

This is what i have so far, i am creating a program that asks the user to enter 7 numbers. These numbers can be any numbers. The end result will give the averages of the positive numbers, the negative numbers, and all the numbers as follows:

```
average positive="" 
average negative="" 
average all=""


import random

def main():
        sum_positive=0 
        count_positive=0 # number of positive 
        sum_negative=0 
        count_negative=0 # number of negative 

    for i in range (7): 
        n=input("Please, enter number %d: " % i) # will display prompt like "Please, enter         number 1:" 
        print ("number entered: ",n) # this will print the entered number, one of the question 
        if n > 0: 
           count_positive += 1 
           sum_positive = sum_positive + n 
        elif n < 0: 
           count_negative += 1 
           sum_negative = sum_negative + n 
    # loop ends here 
    print("Sum of negative number is :", sum_negative) 
    print("Average negative number is : ", sum_negative*1.0/count_negative) 
    print("Sum of positive number is :", sum_positive) 
    print("Average positive number is : ", sum_positive*1.0/count_positive)



main()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: Looks not too far off to me, but `input` in Python 3 always returns a string. You'll need to call `int` on it before comparing to 0, allowing for the possibility of the user entering something other than a number.

Comment: when i run it in idle it gives me an "expected indented block" error sum_positive

Comment: Yeah, your indentation is totally wrong here. I kind of assumed that was an error introduced by cutting and pasting. Indentation is syntax in Python, so that's the first thing you'll need to fix.

Comment: ok i got the indentation to work in idle... what do you mean by calling my input (int)

Comment: Since you're on Python 3, (as indicated by calling `print` as a function) `input` returns a string. If you type `7`, `n` will be the string `'7'`. And if you type `foo`, `n` will be the string `'foo'`. You need to create an integer from the string before you can compare it to `0`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int

Answer (score 1):

A bit neater & more pythonic code.

```
numbers = [input("Please, enter number {}: ".format(i+1)) for i in range(7)]
# will display prompt like "Please, enter number 1:"
print "numbers entered:", numbers # this will print the entered numbers

positives = [num for num in numbers if num >= 0]
negatives = [num for num in numbers if num  < 0]

# loop ends here
print "Sum of negative numbers is :", sum(negatives)
print "Average negative number is :", sum(negatives)*1.0/len(negatives)
print "Sum of positive numbers is :", sum(positives)
print "Average positive number is :", sum(positives)*1.0/len(positives)
```

[`List Comprehensions`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are faster than normal `for` loops & are more pythonic.

[`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) is a built-in function that returns the sum of the integers/floats in the provided iterables.

[`len`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) is a built-in function that returns the length of the list or iterable passed to it.

Note - In Python v3 `print` is a function. Also, `input` behaves like `raw_input`, so for taking integers as input, you should do `int(input())`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
user_input = []
for i in range(7):
    user_input.append(input("Pleace, enter number %d: " % i))

negs = [x for x in user_input if x < 0]
pos  = [x for x in user_input if x > 0]

print "Sum of neg ", sum(negs)
print "Avg of neg ", sum(negs)/float(len(negs))

print "Sum of pos ", sum(pos)
print "Avg of pos ", sum(pos)/float(len(negs))

print "Sum of all ", sum(user_input)
print "Avg of all ", sum(user_input)/float(len(user_input))
```

Comment: `filter` with `lambda` is kind of deprecated, better use list comprehensions instead. `negs = [x for x in user_input if x < 0]` or even a generator with `(`, `)`. A nice summary from Guido here: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196